# AngularJS: ng-show/ng-hide required fields

Tags: angularjs

I am attempting to show/hide a required field using ng-show/ng-hide unless an input is checked to show the field. However, the form won't submit as the hidden fields are required (unless I select the option to view the hidden additional fields). The reason I am using ng-hide on a required field is to display additional fields that may be required only when needed. Is there a method to change the attributes on the "hidden" inputs dynamically?

Example:

```
Check Me to Show Additional Fields
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked">

Additional Fields
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputamount" data-ng-model="itemamount" step="any" required ng-show="checked"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputlocation" data-ng-model="itemlocation" placeholder="Location" required ng-show="checked"/>
```

Comment: You're saying that if you enter data into the 2 input fields below and then hide them the form will not submit?

Comment: By default they are hidden and will not have data in them unless someone checks the box to view the additional fields, so if I try to submit my form, the form won't submit since they are required.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use `ng-required` and it will set the required attribute with correspondence to `checked` boleon of your input model

```
<input type="number" ng-required="{{checked}}" class="form-control" id="inputamount"
 data-ng-model="itemamount" step="any" ng-show="checked"/>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. as the ng-required understands if fields are unchecked as well (ex. hiding fields on check that are required).

Comment: @Kode yeah...glad it helped you, upvote n accept as an answer so it may help others as well :)

Comment: Great, first I have to use ng-show on the element or parent element and then I have to use ng-required on the input.  Thanks angular.